# Android ToDoTask

Tags: android

I am creating todo task application in android. When i adds a multi line task in listview than i want it to show task in multi line view. Each line should be separated by a separator line . How can i do this..

Answer (score 0):

Once you have an `ArrayList<MyTask>`, create an `ArrayAdapter` to use that list into the `ListView` widget.

APIs:

- [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)
- [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html)
- [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

Examples:

- [ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)
- [ListView using ArrayAdapter](http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2010/02/16/using-an-arrayadapter-to-control-a-listviews-data/)